# get keyring password with blank username

Tags: python, python-keyring

I have existing windows credentials in the credential manager with a blank username. It doesn't appear that the `keyring` package can read these:

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("test", "", "mypassword")
keyring.get_password("test", "")  # returns None
```

Running the same commands with a username works fine. I can view the created credential in the windows credential manager utility. It's there. I just can't read it via the `keyring` library. Is there any workaround for this or am I doing something wrong (besides having creds with no username)? Thanks

Comment: That exact code works for me? Only time it returns `None` for me is if that specific service / username combo doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 using python 3.7.7

Comment: Just to be sure, how are you executing the code? Are you pasting it into an interpreter, or is it in a file you're running?

Comment: Also, can you try this and see if that gives the same result: `keyring.get_credential("test", None).password`

Comment: That was it @HampusLarsson, make it an answer and get the points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can use your code "as is" and still retrieve the information:

```
>>> import keyring
>>> keyring.set_password("test", "", "mypassword")
>>> keyring.get_password("test", "")
'mypassword'
```

However, this is not the only way to "retrieve" the credentials. Using the `keyring.get_credential` method, we can get both username and password in one command:

```
>>> x = keyring.get_credential(service_name="test", username=None)
>>> x.username
''
>>> x.password
'mypassword'
```

You have to specify a `username` in the call, but you can just pass `None` to it, and it will fetch the first one it matches.

Comment: `keyring.get_password("test", None)` works for me. Thank you

Comment: using `service_name="x"` is a requirement at the moment for an internal position